# Optimizing Doctrine WHERE Clause with Regex

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

See the Below Doctrine Query:

```
SELECT values, orgunit, form 
    FROM Values values 
    INNER JOIN values.orgunit orgunit 
    INNER JOIN values.form form 
    INNER JOIN orgunit.orgunitStructure orgunitStructure 
    WHERE orgunitStructure.level1Id=123032 
        AND orgunitStructure.level >= (SELECT selectedOrgSructure.level FROM OrgunitStructure selectedOrgSructure WHERE selectedOrgSructure.orgunit=123032 ) 
        AND form.id IN(189,187,190,188) 
        AND ( 
            LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189886":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189880":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189881":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189871":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189888":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189873":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189870":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189863":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189865":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189867":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189869":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189872":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189894":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189896":"10369434"%' 
            OR LOWER(orgunit.longname) LIKE '%10369434%'
            )
```

I'm looking for REGEX Optimization of the WHERE clause, specifically putting the ORs together into something like, from:

```
LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189886":"10369434"%' 
OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189880":"10369434"%' 
OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189881":"10369434"%' 
OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189871":"10369434"%' 
OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189888":"10369434"%' 
OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189873":"10369434"%' 
OR LOWER(values.value) LIKE '%"189870":"10369434"%'
```

Into:

```
LOWER(values.value) REGEXP '%("189886":"10369434")|("189886":"10369434")|("189880":"10369434")|("189881":"10369434")|("189871":"10369434")|("189888":"10369434")|("189873":"10369434")%'
```

Comment: one question: why do you LOWER(values.value) when checking against %"numeric:numeric"% ?

Comment: In some cases the generated Query is %"numeric:string"%, hence the LOWER(values.value) to make it case insenstive.